# Swift CLLocationManager Popup not stay when home button press

Tags: swift, core-location

In swift i am using CLLocationManager, The Problem is when app start then after 2 sec (when showing splashScreen) press home button then app go to background stat then location popup showing only for 1 sec and automatic hide , user cant able to click because location popup automatic hide , and then app go to background to foreground location popup is missing, and when i kill the app then again open app popup is showing or some time not , and setting screen in general there is not option for location allow or not , What i do , where is problem in my code , my be this is problem is ios framework 
Here is my Code

```
Plist
 <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Get Your Location </string>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Get Your Location For </string>

AppDelegate.swift
import CoreLocation


class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate ,CLLocationManagerDelegate {
  let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
 func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        //NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(3);

        self.initLocationManager();

        return true
    }
 func initLocationManager() {


        // locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.distanceFilter  = 40 // Must move at least 1km
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        //self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()



    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        print(locations)
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus)
    {

    }


    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {



      print("Error")

    }

}
```

Please help me , when i check same think from apple store download ola App and Uber App in this app on press home button in splash screen time popup is stay when app in background , But in My code i cant able do . Please help me .

Thankyou 
Regards, 
Nishant Chandwani

Answer (score 0):

Why are you pressing the homeButton just when your app launch ? 
I recommend you to ask for permission in your first ViewController that is displayed and also you have to initialize a CLLocationManager before asking for permission. It's also very convenient to use a singleton for the `CLLocationManager` , so if you have a class named `YourLocationManager.swift` you can use this :

```
    YourLocationManager.swift 

    class YourLocationManager: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    static let sharedInstance = YourLocationManager()

    var locationManager: CLLocationManager?


    func startLocationManager() {
        NSLog("Start UpdatedManagerLocation")
        if locationManager == nil {
            NSLog("Initialize location Manager")
            locationManager = CLLocationManager()
            if let manager = locationManager {
                manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
                manager.distanceFilter = 5.0
                manager.delegate = self
                manager.activityType = CLActivityType.Fitness
                manager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = true
            }
        }
        self.locationManager?.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func stopLocationManager() {
                NSLog("Stop LocationUpdatedManager")
                self.locationManager?.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
                print(locations)
           // Maybe you also want to just print locations.last which is the last position received
     }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        // I recommend you to send a NSNotificationCenter to detect if the user changes it in the settings so that you can handle it 
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
     print("Error")
}
```

And then if you want to ask for the user permission, just start in your viewController or even in your AppDelegate) your location Manager :

```
YourLocationManager.sharedInstance.startLocationManager()
```

Then you ask permission on it :

```
YourLocationManager.sharedInstance.locationManager?.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
```

If I use this not in my AppDelegate the popup asking for userpermission stays even if the app goes background.